# Open selection menus instead of a new buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I use yasnippet for completion it opens up a new buffer to select a list of choices instead of opening up a menu like this [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml) example. How do I make my emacs use the menu? I am using emacs 22.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following configuration in yasnippet to get dropdown lists:

```
(require 'dropdown-list)
(setq yas/prompt-functions '(yas/dropdown-prompt
                             yas/ido-prompt
                             yas/completing-prompt))
```

You can probably get rid of `yas/ido-prompt` and `yas/comleting-prompt`, but I didn't try it.

Yasnippet distribution contains a copy of `dropdown-list.el`, but if you cannot find it, you can download a copy from [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dropdown-list.el)